# FPDI class not starting

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to setup FPDI in my localhost but its gives me an error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'FPDF' not found in C:\wamp\www\book\fpdf_tpl.php on line 20
```

This is what I did:
I went to [download page](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/#p-380), I downloaded 2 packs (FPDF_TPL and FPDI) and unziped them into my localhost.
Then I made a [example page](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/):

```
<?php
    require_once('fpdf.php');
    require_once('fpdi.php');

    // initiate FPDI
    $pdf = new FPDI();

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // set the source file
    $pdf->setSourceFile("PdfDocument.pdf");

    // import page 1
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);

    // use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

    // now write some text above the imported page
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
    $pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

    pdf->Output();
```

I did what the site says, but I had an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FPDF' not found in C:\wamp\www\book\fpdf_tpl.php on line 20
```

I have searched the error codes, but I can not figure it out.
Is there anybody experienced with FPDI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the library in the page [Download](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/#p-304) and extract it to your folder. Then the code should work. Make sure you put the correct path for `require_once`.

Comment: i did it i downloaded both libs but still do not work . which lib you are talking about

Comment: @synan54, you get error in template file downloaded. The code library is the next download entry in the page. Make sure the extracted files in same location, not in different location.

Comment: i downloaded FPDF_TPL Version 1.2.3 and FPDI Version 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

download the fpdf lib from http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php,

with the latest version fpdf17:
require_once('your_dir/fpdf17/fpdf.php');

Answer (score 0):

Add below line into your composer.

```
"require": {
        "setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "1.6.1"
    }
```

and update the composer using below code.

```
composer update setasign/fpdi-fpdf
```

Remove you require function lines and add below line. You will get an output.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
```